# VBA Listbox column to display alternative text

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

This code only gives me "Confirmed" on the last line of the ListBox? any ideas on how to do it for all lines?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

With ListBox1
For i = 1 To 200
If .List(1, 1) = "O/C" Then
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = "Confirmed"
        End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Suppose you mean `For i = 0 to .ListCount-1`, then `If .List(i, 1) = "0/C" Then` and `.List(i, 4) = "Confirmed"`;  take into account that listindex is zerobound (as well as the column indices in the list, so by indicating `.List(i,1)` you get the 2nd list col and 4 actually refers to the 5th list col!) @Andy
`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this work:

```
.AddItem Worksheets(TextBox3.Value).Range("B" & i + 5).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = fnd.Offset(i + 3, 0)
            If .List(1, 1) = "Y" Then
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Confirmed"
            End if
```